# Problem with JPA2 and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have this problem:

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: fb-persistence] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
    at it.synclab.fb.test.Test.main(Test.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.bind(PropertyBinder.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2061)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:4008)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3962)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1371)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1348)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1522)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1100)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:366)
    ... 4 more
```

Who can help me to solve? I have configured Hibernate with JPA, the file persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="fb-persistence" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>it.synclab.fb.jpa.Plugin</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> 
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="***"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="***"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:RAFFAELE"/>
        </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and my class with the mapping is:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity @Table(name="PLUGIN")
public class Plugin {

    private int id;


    private String nome;


    private String descrizione;


    public Plugin(){}

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="NOME")
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Column(name="DESCRIZIONE")
    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Plugin other = (Plugin) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

What is the problem? Help me? I was forgetting, i have configured the dependenci with maven2 and file pom.xml is:

```
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the main class you are using?

Comment: ops excuse ...in the main class i call "EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("fb-persistence");"

Comment: Are you sure `Plugin` is the only persistent class?

Comment: I'm just testing this class but i have more class Entity

Comment: @giulius: Try to add `<exclude-unlisted-classes/>` to `persistence.xml` - if problem disappears, it's caused by other entities.

Comment: @axtavt: I added <exclude-unlisted-classes> true </ exclude-unlisted-classes> but this bypasses the problem does not solve it

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that you have more than one hibernate jar on your classpath and that's why it's throwing a class cast exception.

The other bit that looks wrong (but might be right) is that you're using JTA transactions. If you have no clue what JTA means, change the transaction-type on persistance.xml to `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"`

Comment: I have changed the trasaction-type on persistence.xml and I checked the libraries of the class path, even if I resolve dependencies with maven? Anyway the problem persist...Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Maven won't put duplicate jars in the classpath, but you might be importing 2 hibernate jars with different group or artifact ids. Run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true` and check that maven in not putting 2 versions of Hibernate on the class path.

Comment: It seems that Maven does not put duplicate jars in the classpath. I checked into the repository (.m/), the "target\classes" folder and in the libraries of "build path" of Eclipse. I have seen in the right places?

Comment: Mmm I just checked the class hierarchy on Hibernate 3.6.2 (the version I'm using at the moment) and RootClass and UnionSubClass are not related, they have a common superclass, but they don't inherit from each other. This could be because there's a horrible bug in hibernate 3.6.3 (which I doubt) or because there are some libraries which are conflicting. Again, it looks like you have a classpath issue, but with incompatible classes. Sorry that I can't help you more.

Comment: I cheked the file ".classpath" of eclipse and not have duplicate library for hibernate . If you want I can post the file? Thank you for all your help so far

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this error when having Entity beans that inherited from one another. Even though they were corectly annotated (in accordance to JPA2 specs), they didn't work in Hibernate (there are numerous such bugs with Hibernate JPA2 implementation). Finally what I did is add very specific (though not mandatory from JPA2s point of view) configuration (via annotations) for the discriminator column (`@DiscriminatorValue("SomeValue")`), the columns used for the JOINs (`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "idColumn")`). From your code snipped it doesn't appear that you're using inheritance, but if you infact are, try that.

Also, if your project allows it, switch from Hibernate to Eclipselink as a JPA2 implementation. I had countless occurances where correct JPA2 code worked fine in EclipseLink but threw bizzare exceptions in Hibernate.